# Deleting or Updating posts in LARAVEL using controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, http-put

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>['PostsController@update',$post->id],'method'=>'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title', $post->title,['class'=>'form- 
           control','placeholder'=>'Title'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
            {{Form::textarea('body', $post->body,['id'=>'article 
            ckeditor','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Body Text'])}}
        </div>
        {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
        {{Form::submit('Update',['class'=>'btn btn-success'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I am using this `{{ Form::hidden('_method','PUT') }}` to update my post because there is no other way. Is there any better way or not?

Here is my controller (postcontroller):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    $post = Post::find($id);

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->body = $request->body;

    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post Updated Sucessfully');
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question / problem

Comment: `'method'=>'POST'` in Form::open - Shouldn't that be `method'=>'PUT'`? Not really sure what's being asked here.

Comment: You can use put instead of post. Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'put'])

Answer (score 0):

This is the default and correct way to use UPDATE form. You have to use POST in form method and PUT as request parameter (hidden) with form.

What you missed here is CSRF token in form, which can be used in multiple ways like:

```
{!! Form::token() !!}

{!! Form::hidden('_token', Session::token()) !!}

{!! csrf_field() !!}

@csrf <!-- since Laravel 5.6 -->
```

Similarly, you can use PUT as:

```
@method('PUT')
```